# Can not install rcompanion package in r. R version 3.4.3

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install rcompanion package in r but I am getting these error. any idea?

- installing *source* package ‘mixOmics’ ...
  ** package ‘mixOmics’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Error : objects ‘layout3d’, ‘legend3d’, ‘next3d’ are not exported by 'namespace:rgl'
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘mixOmics’
- removing ‘/home/amir/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/mixOmics’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mixOmics’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘mixOmics’ is not available for package ‘RVAideMemoire’
- removing ‘/home/amir/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/RVAideMemoire’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RVAideMemoire’ had non-zero exit status
  ERROR: dependency ‘RVAideMemoire’ is not available for package ‘rcompanion’
- removing ‘/home/amir/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rcompanion’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rcompanion’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpxbpbJJ/downloaded_packages’

Comment: I won't be much help here, but I will note that the rcompanion package [passes all its checks](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_rcompanion.html).  The package itself is pretty simple, but it does install a bunch of other packages. It looks like the error is stemming from the mixOmics package that RVAideMemoire imports, which is imported by rcompanion.  I don't have much to suggest other than the usual:  restart R and RStudio, uninstall and reinstall the packages.  Try to install mixOmics directly first. Then RVAideMemoire. Then rcompanion.  If not, contact package authors.

Comment: The `rcompanion` has since been modified so that it does not import the `RVAideMemoire` package, since apparently it was causing some installation problems for some.

Answer (score 0):

Rcompanion relies on missing packages. I solved installing `r-cran-rgl` with

```
sudo apt install r-cran-rgl
```

and then install again `rcompanion`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that some month ago. At the time of the reply it worked. Probably some dependencies changed